# <QRandomGenerator> No such file or directory

Tags: c++11, qt5

Im trying to implement the Threaded fortune example from QT5 documentation(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) but the compiler doesn't accept the header . In the .pro file have CONFIG+=c++11 which works works fine for other headers but not for this one.

I tryed to include different configuration option in the .pro file including CONFIG += staticlib c++11 which DOESn't work!

The .pro file looks like this:

[image]

The fortunserver.h file looks like:

[image]

I expect the program to build successfully with the header QRandomGenerator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text are not as useful as the text they contain. Replacing, or augmenting those images with the text makes it searchable, and accessible, and improves your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: please post a screenshot of the "
Build settings"

Comment: I guess you're missing a Qt += core in .pro

Answer (score 4):

`QRandomGenerator` is a newly added class, [only available since QT 5.10](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrandomgenerator.html).

If you are using an older version of Qt this class will not be available. You can check your QT version by going to Tools > Options > Kits > (your kit) > QT Version.

If this is <5.10 you will need to update Qt. On Linux this means that you may have to download Qt from their website rather than through your package manager.

Once you have downloaded a new version of Qt, change your kit Qt version to it and then rebuild.